Prove that $F(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x(1+t^2)}}{1+t^2}dt$ is continious $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$
Prove that $F(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x(1+t^2)}}{1+t^2}dt$ is continious $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. First of all, for every  $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we are integrating a continious function in $[0,1]$ hence integrable function. Now, I was searching for some theorem that states something similar to the improper integral:

If $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$ then the function $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ is continious for every $x\in [a,b]$.

I couldn't figure out if there is something similar for my problem or if I could change the limits of integration to have something similar so I went to the definition of continuity in the analytic field and:

$F(x)$ will be continious in a point where it is defined if and only if For every $\epsilon>0$ exist $\delta>0$ such that for every $|c-x|<\delta$ we have $|F(c)-F(x)|<\epsilon$

Doing the math of the last inequality I get:

$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-c(1+t^2)}(e^{-\delta(1+t^2)}-1)}{1+t^2}dt <F(c)-F(x)<\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-c(1+t^2)}(e^{\delta(1+t^2)}-1)}{1+t^2}dt$

That ensures the continuity. Is there a better method to prove this, and is there something wrong with the proof? Thanks!

It suffices to show that $F$ is continuous on every closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$. The partial derivative of $e^{-x(1+t^2)}$ with respect to $x$ is $-(1+t^2)e^{-x(1+t^2)}$, which is bounded by $(1+t^2)e^{2\max\{|a|,|b|\}}$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ and $t\in [0,1]$. By the mean value theorem, $$|e^{-x(1+t^2)} - e^{-y(1+t^2)}| \le (1+t^2)e^{2\max\{|a|,|b|\}}|x-y|$$ for all $x,y\in [a,b]$ and $t\in [0,1]$. We obtain the estimate $$|F(x) - F(y)| \le \int_0^1 \frac{|e^{-x(1+t^2)} - e^{-y(1+t^2)}|}{1+t^2}\, dt\le e^{2\max\{|a|,|b|\}}|x-y|$$on $[a,b]$, which shows $F$ is continuous (in fact, Lipschitz continuous) on $[a,b]$.
